# how do i replicate the stackoverflow close button click to replace confirmation pages in asp.net-mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i have taken over an asp.net mvc and i there are a lot of actions that require user confirmation.  The current implementation is to have a separate View for each of these confirmation pages.

i thought it would be slicker to use jquery to have a little popup when you click "delete user" for example that shows the user confirmation there ("Are you sure you want to delete user "xx"?)

**I want this to work similar to when you click on "CLOSE" on a stackoverflow question.  You get the inline popup to confrim and then submit**

any suggestions where to start?  Should this still be another view or should this code be embedded in the regular view that has the actions? i have been playing around with the jquery samples but i feel like i am still very much guessing on the best practice here.

So I went to view the page source of stackoverflow to look at what happens when you click on the close button but all i see is:

```
<a id="close-question-1238657" title="closes/opens question for answering; when closed, no more answers can be added">close</a>
```

i dont see what is calling the popup

Comment: Hmmm, I guess you can remove the hardcoded message, and put it in a variable which you can set from code.

Comment: i am a javascript newbie . . any example code would be appreciated in terms of how to pass a variable into a javascript function

Comment: If you are talking about the confirm.js, then its given as an EXAMPLE ONLY! You can copy the code, and write your own. Btw, you can take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery UI Dialog](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from jQuery UI Dialog, you can also try [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal/) by [Eric Martin](http://www.ericmmartin.com/).

### EDIT

The code given in the confirm.js contains two method definitions. One is a generic method called `confirm`, which will create your modal popup with the message you want to be displayed. You have to use this method whenever you want to create the modal popup.

```
confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", function() {
    //Here you will write the code that will handle the click of the OK button.
});
```

Here, the second argument is a function (this works almost like a delegate in C#). What will happen is that the `confirm` function will show a dialog containing your message, and when the user clicks any button, the anonymous function passed as the second argument will be invoked. You can also write a "normal" function and pass it as a second argument to `confirm` -

```
function callbackHandler() {
    //Here you will write the code that will handle the click of the OK button.
}

confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?", callbackHandler);
```

Your function will be invoked by this piece of code -

```
// if the user clicks "yes"
dialog.data.find('.yes').click(function () {
    // call the callback
    if ($.isFunction(callback)) { callback.apply(); }
    // close the dialog
    $.modal.close();
});
```

Comment: i like the confirm override button but the data inthe confirmation screen and the link are hard coded in the .js file.  is there anyway to pass that data in ?